# Android How to make app locker

Tags: android, passwords, password-protection

I am new to Android so dont kill me if this question has been repeated but believe me I searched a lot and could not find any usful answer. My question is how to implement the app locker for all applications that have been installed on device. I can set app lock on my app via code but how to implement it on others installed apps as well.
Thank you!

Comment: "Searched a lot" - I don't think so! If you had searched just this forum alone with the terms [android] and "app locker", you would have found 7 identical questions. Nearly all the answers were "you can't do it". Surprisingly only 2 of the questions got closed, I'm voting to make it 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android App Locker Help Required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839714/android-app-locker-help-required)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

Android apps are not allowed to control or restrict access to other apps via the public SDK.

The only way you can semi achieve this is by writing your own custom launcher that allows locks to be set on apps, as then you can intercept and run code when the user launches an app from the app list. However, this approach does not stop a user from circumnavigating your lock by using recent apps or installing another launcher.